# Which way is correct to connect to SQL Server for transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Which way is more correct to delete entity?

Correct means: for a lot of rows, we should use way that is more trust-able and close transaction after end of work

**First** attempt:

```
public class UserRepository : IDisposable
{
    private DomainModels.BotEntities _dbDnt = null;

    public UserRepository()
    {
        _dbDnt = new DomainModels.IraniBotEntities();
    }

    public bool Delete(int id, bool autoSave = true)
    {
        try
        {
            var entity = _dbDnt.Users.Find(id);
            _dbDnt.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;

            if (autoSave)
                return Convert.ToBoolean(_dbDnt.SaveChanges());
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        try
        {
            return _dbDnt.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (this._dbDnt != null)
            {
                this._dbDnt.Dispose();
                this._dbDnt = null;
            }
        }
    }

    ~UserRepository()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

and then use like this :

```
   UserRepository repA = new UserRepository();
   repA.Delete(user);
```

**Second** attempt:

```
        using (var dbContext = new IraniBotEntities())
        {
            dbContext.Users.Remove(user);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Which way is more correct? Because I'm using hangfire with first way and my cpu on server is going to 100%

Comment: Second.  You should always dispose of DB resources as soon as you're down with a single unit of work.  With that said it might not be why your CPU  "going to 100%" though.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Neither way should cause your CPU to go that high. Something else is wrong here. Either method you've posted should be fine. You need to profile your application to discover what's going on. The first way has an advantage that you can perform multiple operations before calling SaveChanges, thus you can perform a single transaction across multiple statements. So don't listen to those that are saying saying the 2nd method is always best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be choosing 2nd way instead of first.

for deleting multiple rows you can do as mentioned below.

```
using (var dbContext = new IraniBotEntities())
 {
     var allRec= dbContext.Users;
     dbContext.Users.RemoveRange(allRec);
     dbContext.SaveChanges();
 }
```